# Magento admin: Newly added blocks not loading

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a custom module where many custom blocks are defined already and they work fine.

But, when I am trying to add a new block in my module's layout file, the block does not display. When I add the new block as a child block of an existing block, it displays.

If I change the name of an existing block, that block disappears.

I researched a lot on this to find whether a block needs something else to be done for displaying in addition to putting it in layout xml. But didn't find any hint.

Any ideas on this? Am I missing something somewhere which is causing my new blocks to not to load. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your template files, usually something like

```
$this->getChildHtml('blockname');
```

is called to display blocks. That means if you change your block name in the XML file, but not in the .phtml file, the block will not be rendered.

Same thing for your new block - you have to call `$this->getChildHtml('newblockname');` somewhere in the template file.

Sending over the XML contents might help me be more accurate.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. In fact, my other template files do have such statements but they and their blocks load fine. :(